# java block inside the subprojects is not working in gradle kotlin dsl

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I would like to set java version for all of my subproject to 17.

Below is my gradle file of main project -

```
group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

subprojects {
    apply(plugin = "java")
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }

    configure<JavaCompile> {
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17.toString()
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17.toString()
    }

    java {
        toolchain {
            languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))
        }
    }
}
```

when I run the command `gradle clean build` I get the below error -

> % gradle clean build
>
> > Configure project :
> > e: file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/org-example/build.gradle.kts:28:5: Expression 'java' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found
> > e: file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/org-example/build.gradle.kts:28:5: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
> > public val PluginDependenciesSpec.java: PluginDependencySpec defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
> > e: file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/org-example/build.gradle.kts:29:9: Unresolved reference: toolchain
> > e: file:///Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/org-example/build.gradle.kts:30:13: Unresolved reference: languageVersion
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Any idea how to fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use type-safe accessors with `subprojects { }`. Additionally, you are appearing to convert Groovy DSL to Kotlin based on your usage of `configure<JavaCompile>`. What you want is the following:

```
subprojects {
    configure<JavaPluginExtension> {
        java {
            toolchain {
                languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that targetCompatibility/sourceCompatibility defaults to whatever the toolchain is configured to. Since you are configuring them to be the same as the toolchain, I've omitted it from above.

However, if you do need to configure all `JavaCompile` tasks, then:

```
subprojects {
    configure<JavaPluginExtension> {
        java {
            toolchain {
                languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))
            }
        }
    }
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile::class).configureEach {
        // ...task configuration
    }
}
```

Comment: I get same error even after adding your suggestion "Expression 'java' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found"